# UITextField won't save text into CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield

This UITextField is created programmatically and resides in a custom UITableViewCell. The UITableViewCell is also the delegate of the UITextField and implements the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol. Everything seems to be working fine except that when I reload the app none of the text is saved within CoreData. I have tried to make the TableViewController the delegate for this class but it doesn't seem to work, and in fact crashes the app with an unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

Here is the code for my `textFieldDidEndEditing` method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    Parts *item ; // the NSManagedObject

    item.itemTitle = _itemLabel.text; //_itemLabel is a custom UITextField Class, and itemTitle is a string attribute of the NSManagedObject


    NSError *error;
    [item.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

}
```

and this is the part of the custom `init` method that creates the UITextField:

```
_itemLabel = [[TehdaLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    _itemLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _itemLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    _itemLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _itemLabel.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    _itemLabel.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    _itemLabel.placeholder = @"Type some stuff here!";
    _itemLabel.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:_itemLabel];
```

Everything else works fine, saving the text in CoreData just refuses to work for me.

EDIT: the `insertObject` method within my TableViewController

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
Parts *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    MCSwipeTableViewCell *editCell;
    for (MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]){
        if (cell.itemLabel.text == item.itemTitle) {
        //if (cell.itemLabel.text == item.itemTitle) {
            editCell = cell;
            break;
        }
    }
    editCell.itemLabel.text = item.itemTitle;
    [editCell.itemLabel becomeFirstResponder];

    [item setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"itemDate"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: In the textFieldDidEndEditing method, what do you get if you log _itemLabel.text?

Comment: I added the log right after `item.itemTitle = _itemLabel.text` and it gives me whatever text is typed into the field. But if I scroll away or rebuild the app the text is gone.

Comment: Where do u call "insertObject" method?

Comment: In my TableViewController

Answer (score 1):

You didn't insert your entity "Parts" into CoreData.

```
Parts *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parts"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

And now it will save it...

Comment: In my TableViewController I actually do this inside the `insertObject` method. I'll edit the top post to show the code in there.

Comment: So I also tried the adjusting the code to work in my TableViewController, I set the textfield delegate to the TableViewController instead of the cell, added `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and now it crashes at `cell.itemLabel.text = item.itemTitle;` giving the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. All necessary headers imported and pointers set up.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initialising item, it is a nil object.